# TypeError : takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given) : request argument is not being passed

Tags: python, django

So i have this in my views.py

```
def rate_api(request, rating_user_id, rated_user_id, value):
    user.profile = request.user.get_profile()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

And this in my urls.py

```
url(r'^rate_api/(?P<rating_user_id>.+?)/(?P<rated_user_id>.+?)/$', 'v1_1.views.rate_api'),
```

And this in my template (profile.html)

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "../../rate_api/variable1/variable2/variable3",
          data: '',
        });
```

And I get the following error

```
TypeError at /rate_api/variable1/variable2/variable3/
rate_api() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Request Method: GET
```

I believe that the parameter request is not being passed. How can i fix this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's the `value` parameter that isn't being passed, because you're not capturing it in your regex.